# How to delete hive table records ?

Tags: hive, hdfs, bigdata, hiveql

how to delete hive table  records, we have 100 records there and i need to delete 10 records only, 
when i use

> dfs -rmr table_name whole table deleted 
>   if any chance to delete in Hbase , send to data in Hbase,

Answer (score 2):

You cannot delete directly from Hive table,
However, you can use a workaround of overwriting into Hive table

```
insert overwrite into table_name
select * from table_name
where id in (1,2,3,...)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't delete data from Hive tables since it is already written in the files in HDFS. You can only drop partitions which deletes directories in HDFS. So best practice is to have partitions if you want to delete in the future.

Answer (score 0):

To delete records in a table, you can use the SQL syntax from your hive client :

```
 DELETE FROM tablename [WHERE expression]
```

Comment: thanks for replaying i need first 10 records deletion out of 100 records

Answer (score 0):

Try with where and your key with in clause

```
DELETE FROM tablename where id in (select id from tablename limit 10);
```

**Example:-**
I had acid transactional table in hive

```
select * from trans;
+-----+-------+--+
| id  | name  |
+-----+-------+--+
| 2   | hcc   |
| 1   | hi    |
| 3   | hdp   |
+-----+-------+--+
```

Now i want to delete only 2 then my delete statement would be

```
delete from trans where id in (select id from trans limit 1);
```

**Result:-**

```
select * from trans;
+-----+-------+--+
| id  | name  |
+-----+-------+--+
| 1   | hi    |
| 3   | hdp   |
+-----+-------+--+
```

So we have just deleted the first record like this way you can specify limit 10 then hive can delete first 10 records.

you can specify orderby... some other clauses in your subquery if you need to delete only first 10 having specific order(like delete id's from 1 to 10).